# How to loop a command for a discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm a newbie and I am trying to make a discord bot go to a specific channel(I've done that) and execute channel.bulkDelete(100) but I am having problems as In I know that there is a better way to do this, than just copy-pasting it, I just don't know how, is there a loop that I could use?

Comment: Would you like to loop it x amount of times, every hour...?

Comment: Not every hour, every second, since I need it to delete quite a lot of text and the max delete is 100, I don't want to copy-paste the command like a million times so I can get everything deleted. But yea, loop it x times but in a very short time span, short as possible.

Comment: The limit of 100 is set with reasons. So don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Loop it x times but in a very short time span, short as possible.

What you're looking for is a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). You can use one like so:

```js
const times = 5; // example

for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
  console.log(`number ${i}`);
}
```

** Note that a block statement isn't required if you're executing just a single statement.*

---

However, do keep in mind what @PLASMA chicken pointed out:

> The limit of 100 is set with reasons.

You also can't bulk delete messages older than 2 weeks. If you're looking to simply clear a channel and you're sure its ID or webhooks aren't needed, you can create a new one with the same properties, appearing identical. Otherwise, I would strongly advise against bulk deleting in a loop.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just use that delete and make a new channel method, since, as you said, it will be hard for me to delete as much messages as I need to, so I will opt out for that option, thanks for the response.

Comment: [`GuildChannel.clone()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=clone) should help with that.